# Saving image using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I made a program in MATLAB to generate images with different specifications, but each time I change one of theses specifications I had to re-save the image under a different name and path. So, I made a for loop to change these specifications, but I don't know how I can make MATLAB save the generated image with different names and different paths...

***How can I write a program to make MATLAB save multiple generated images with different names and different paths as a part of `for`–loop?***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put something like this at the end of your loop:

```
for i = 1:n
  <your loop code>
  file_name=sprintf('%d.jpg',i);  % assuming you are saving image as a .jpg
  imwrite(your_image, file_name);  % or something like this, however you choose to save your image
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save JPEG, PNG etc., then see @AGS's post. If you want to save FIG files, use

```
hgsave(gcf, file_name)
```

instead of the `imwrite` line. There's also

```
print('-djpeg', file_name)  %# for JPEG file (lossy)
print('-dpng', file_name)   %# for PNG file (lossless)
```

as an alternative for `imwrite`.

Comment: When using `print` the image should be displayed first by some function such as `imshow`.

Answer (score 0):

Since I wanted to save the plots in my loop in a specific folder in my present working directory (pwd), I modified my naming routine as follows:

```
for s = 1:10
    for i = 1:10 
    <loop commands>
    end
end

% prints stimuli to folder created for them
file_name=sprintf('%s/eb_imgs/%0.3f.tif',pwd,s(i)); % pwd = path of present working  
                                                    % directory and s(i) = the value 
                                                    % of the changing variable
                                                    % that I wanted to document

file_name = /Users/Miriam/Documents/PSYC/eb_imgs/0.700.tif % how my filename appears
print('-dtiff', '-r300', file_name); % this saves my file to my desired location
```

[matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) [matlab-path](/questions/tagged/matlab-path)